# Can't find a Xamarin.Android Unit Test Project for C#?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to create an Android Unit Test Project for a course I'm working on.

Strangely enough, whenever I try and find a Xamarin.Android/IOS Unit Test Project, I can only see a result for an F# Xamarin.Android Unit test Project, not for C#:

[image]

As you can see by the screenshot, I cannot find any Unit Test App for Andriod/IOS that runs on C#. This is strange as I downloaded everything needed on the installer, maybe I've forgotten to download a specific package? Help would be appreciated; this is all the information I can give.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, it's unfortunately. We can not see the C# Unit for Android. You could request this feature [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8). Later we can follow it up there.

Comment: Junior Jiang, that's strange as it did appear on this particular Pluralsight course: (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/testing-xamarin-forms-applications/table-of-contents) Care to help or clarify?

Comment: Okey, you could check what the version of Visual Stuido is used first. Beause the previous version fo Visual Studio owns this option to create C# Unit Test in Android.

Comment: So 2017 you mean? So no Android-Only Unit test projects for VS 2019?

Comment: Hi, maybe both of the current version of VS 2017 and VS 2019 all now own this option.

Comment: That's strange because I can't find the option for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222757/discussion-between-tommy99-and-junior-jiang-msft).